# Not able to click on a element in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing Java code to automate one process but when I am trying to click on the button which has foloowing code

```
<em class="k-ico-new-post"></em>
<ins class="visuallyHidden">Create Post</ins>
```

I am not able to click on it. I have tried all possible solutions but nothing is working for me. please help what should I write ?

I am writing code like this

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/ins")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/ins")).click();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("em.k-ico-new-post")));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("em.k-ico-new-post")).click();
```

This is my HTML page code

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="titleBar" role="banner">
        <h1 class="visuallyHidden">Welcome To Page</h1>
        <ul id="skip" class="skip visuallyHidden">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse ng-scope" ng-controller="PlaceholderCtlr">
            <div class="headerSplashStrip loaded"></div>
            <div class="navbar-inner mega-menu">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a id="js_knome-brand" class="brand" accesskey="1" href="/">
                    <img class="visuallyHidden" src="print-5d795ba4408e17b69656ca7e2ac042a6.png" aria-hidden="true" alt="Page Logo">
                    <div class="Page-credits">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <span class="nav-search rel">
                            <ul id="js_accessible_notify_converse" class="nav pull-right ng-scope" role="region" ng-controller="NotificationMessagesCtlr" aria-label="utility">
                            <li id="js_messages_container" class="dropdown">
                            <li id="js_notifications_container" class="dropdown">`enter code here`
                            <li class="divider-vertical visible-desktop"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown visible-desktop">
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                            <li class="nav-post">
                                <a id="wa_global_kso_create" class="page-tooltipped js_create_new_post primary" href="#" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Create new post">
                                <em class="k-ico-new-post"></em>
                                <ins class="visuallyHidden">Create Post</ins>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                            <li class="headerProfilethumb dropdown js_user_profile">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="page-ajax-loader-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did u get any exception?

Comment: I am getting following exception  org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/ins

Comment: I tried to increase time but I am not able to click on it

Comment: first try by  cssselector instead of xpath and than click using javascript.

Comment: Clicking wont work until I am able to find the element, its not finding element

Comment: Is the element visible in the web page. Am asking this because the class name given in HTML is showing as "visuallyHidden".

Comment: Yah element is visible and it's fixed on the top of the page

Comment: river.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/em")).click(); worked for me thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Button Name')]")).click();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: It is locating the element by its text (InnerHTML) instead of using an XPath.  This could be a good idea if you know that the text is going to remain the same, but using the id is generally a better bet for tests that don't break when the page changes.

Comment: river.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/em")).click(); worked for me thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try like below

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("$('#wa_global_kso_create .visuallyHidden').click();");
```

UPDATE :

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("$('#js_knome-brand .page-tooltipped').click();");
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for presence of element located by:

Comment: Thanks Raj, First time when I ran with updated code it worked for me but second time it didnt work, do you know why ?

Comment: Fist of all it should have worked for every itearation but ok can you post the error for the second run when it not worked

Comment: Now its not clicking on the item and error also not coming. Let me explain you problem briefly, It's a container fluid in bootstarp which is appended on the top of the page, when we scroll page up and down that header will remain same. So I think in source code of this particular page Selenium webdriver is unable to find this head which contains some buttons including Create Post button. I have tried all possible solution including Selenium IDE, I recorded script using Selenium IED and replay it but it is also failing during run time, Selenium IDE is not able to find that particular element

Comment: river.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/em")).click(); worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't find the element because your xpath

```
//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/ins
```

Does not point to a tag in your document.

The "/ins" at the end implies that your ins tag is a **child** of the anchor tag with id 'wa_global_kso_create' when in fact, the ins is a following-sibling.

You can remove the /ins from the end of the xpath to interact with the anchor tag

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']")).click();
```

The code above should work fine, but if you need to interact with the ins tag instead of the anchor, you could use this xpath

```
//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/following-sibling::ins[1]
```

Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp for a list of Xpath axes.

[FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug) or [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath) can be used to generate XPaths instead of writing them manually.

Comment: I am getting following Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //a[@id='wa_global_kso_create'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: sajid, you will have more success if you install Firefox and use Firebug in order to locate your XPaths. You can install FireBug from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/  Here are some instructions on how to use it to make an XPath directly from your document: http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug -- or you can try FirePath: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/

Comment: Let me explain you problem, It's a container fluid in bootstarp which is appended on the top of the page, when we scroll page up and down that header will remain same. So I think in source code of this particular page Selenium webdriver is unable to find this head which contains some buttons including Create Post button. I have tried all possible solution including Selenium IDE, I recorded script using Selenium IED and replay it but it is also failing during run time, Selenium IDE is not able to find that particular element.

Comment: river.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@id='wa_global_kso_create']/em")).click(); this worked for me thanks for your help bro